# Kolkov editor | Duplicate Element Attributes In Next Line On Enter

Tags: kolkov-editor

I am facing a issue on kolkov rich text editor, i.e. whenever pressing enter for next line, duplicate element is creating on next line with same id selector. steps to reproduce.

Step 1: I have a element in editor (first line) like:

First Div
then
[See First Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaJXq.png)

Step 2: Enter from first line then in second line getting <div id="FirstDiv>.
[Second Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBoT8.png)

Note: Not Sure , is this a functionality or an issue, but it is causing duplicate Id issue for same element. Please let me know if there is any existing solution for this.

Thanks

On Enter Id should not be same. if id will be same how we will recognize the element